# Dropdown list inside the HTML header table

Tags: html, css

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--JS files-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><div class="row-fluid top-space-20">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Student Email</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Grade
                        <select class="form-control" id="statusFilter">
                        <option value="">Student grade</option>
                        <option value="Grade A">A</option>
                <option value="Grade B">B</option>
                            <option value="Grade C">C</option>
                            <option value="Grade D">D</option>
                            <option value="Grade E">E</option>
                            <option value="Grade F">F</option>
                            <option value="Grade G">G</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>Actions</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I want to add the drop down list besides the HTML header. I wante to see only the dropdown arrow head beside the header. But as of now I can see the expanded dropdown and it's below the header.
The HTML code is

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--JS files-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><div class="row-fluid top-space-20">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Student Email</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Grade
                        <select class="form-control" id="statusFilter">
                        <option value="">Student grade</option>
                        <option value="Grade A">A</option>
                <option value="Grade B">B</option>
                            <option value="Grade C">C</option>
                            <option value="Grade D">D</option>
                            <option value="Grade E">E</option>
                            <option value="Grade F">F</option>
                            <option value="Grade G">G</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>Actions</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I can see that drop down is very large and I can see it's below the grade header. I want only the dropdown arrow should be visible?How should I do it?
I am new to the HTML can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tell what you are trying to do we can suggest an alternate solution for that problem. But if you need it as asked there is a workaround. Assign 18px width for the select element.

Comment: I can see the dropdown list size is reduced but i want one more option also. I want the grade and dropdown should be in the same row. As of now dropdown is below the grade header

Comment: You have two options. You can use float: right or display:inline. I would suggest you to go with display property. Also you will have to edit the dropdown more like border and margin none, Aligning the grade and dropdown equally.