# Dropdown works in Chrome not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Dropdown list inside the HTML header table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959596/dropdown-list-inside-the-html-header-table)

I have asked the question in the above link and it got fixed but it was working only in Chrome not in Firefox.What I need here is I need only the dropdown arrow header should be displayed besides the table header. But Now I can see it's only displays below the header and in full width.

```css
.drop-down {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--JS files-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row-fluid top-space-20">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Student Email</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Grade
          <select class=".drop-down form-control" id="statusFilter">
            <option value="">Student grade</option>
            <option value="Grade A">A</option>
            <option value="Grade B">B</option>
            <option value="Grade C">C</option>
            <option value="Grade D">D</option>
            <option value="Grade E">E</option>
            <option value="Grade F">F</option>
            <option value="Grade G">G</option>
          </select>
        </th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I kept the width is small and I tried display:inline.Nothing worked.
Nothing worked.
So what I need is my dropdown should only be visible with arrow head and besides to the Grade header.Not below the Grade header

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the .form-control class getting a block display. Try this in the CSS

```
.form-control{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; /* or whatever width looks good for your purpose */
}
```

You might then need to play around with the margins or vertical alignment to get the table headers looking good

[image: screenshot of result]

Comment: Thanks, I can see dropdown size is reduced it working fine in Chrome. But when I do it in the Firefox I can see the alphabet instead of arrow head.

Comment: if you make the width 50px (or larger) the dropdown arrow will show up on firefox...at least for me it does

Comment: Yes I can see the dropdwon header in the Firefox but along with that I can read some alphabets also. is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: make the first option empty `<option value=""></option>`